# Building master after merging a pull request that was successfully built

Tags: git, pull-request

Is there any advantage to reapplying the same build process to master after successfully using the same build process to validate a pull request for a branch?

eg. Can I be assured that because unit tests ran in the pull request that there is no need to execute them again in master after the pull request has merged?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your pull request is current w/r/t master (that is, it is a fast-forward update from master to the PR), then the content of the pull request is going to be identical to what you end up with after merging it into the `master` branch.

If there have been any intervening changes to `master` since the pull request was branched, then you have no such guarantees.  In this case, your options are either to merge it anyway and then re-test on `master`, or to rebase the pull request and re-test it before merging.  I would favor the latter.

Comment: Right.. so if the pull request can made to 'auto merge' as long as master hasn't changed since the PR build ran then everything should be good.